# Notepad++ does not open files in tabs

Tags: notepad++

I've used Notepad++ for years. Normally, right-clicking a file and choosing "edit with Notepad++" opens it as a tab, allowing for easy cross-referencing during development. However, with new installations (not updates), opening files launches a new Notepad++ instance. There's a preference setting to prevent this, but it doesn't persist after closing Notepad++. Why is this occurring?

Notepad++ v8.6 64-bit

Comment: Which version? Installed 64 bit? Installed to Program Files? Is the user who installed it the same as the one running it?

Comment: installed to Program Files. Different computers. Notepad++ v8.6 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Settings -> Preferences -> Multi-Instance and Date.
2. On the Multi-Instance settings, select Default (mono-instance).
3. Restart Notepad++

[image]